# Is there a fast way to find and insert a symbol in PowerPoint 2013?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, symbols, microsoft-powerpoint-2003

Is there a fast way to find and insert a symbol in PowerPoint 2013?

When I have to insert a symbol, I click *Symbol* and then locate the desired symbol in the table.

However, this takes me a lot of time because I don't know exactly which subset the symbol is in.

I am wondering if there is a fast way to do that? For example, I want to insert a symbol for "ohm", is it possible to locate it within 10 seconds?

[image: Symbol table in PowerPoint 2013]

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect for your question? How do you want to find it if you don't know neither its subset, neither its name (it's a big omega)? Do you want to bookmark / select symbols somehow? You can you keyboard shortcuts to get to symbols table (Alt+N+U), but then it's just question of practice to find it quickly.

Comment: I would like to see if there is a way to find a symbol fast in some way. Currently, I have to look for it in all subset.

Comment: Are you envisioning something like a way to display a huge set of symbols in one window. or a way to collect the symbols you use into a custom selection window?  Beyond that, I'm thinking you need a computer with ESP.